# Any tool to convert .jar to .apk on Windows

Tags: windows, file-conversion

I would like to convert .Jar files (Java mobile application) to a Android downloadable software (Android apps)

Can anyone suggest a software tool for Windows platform?

**Please be advised**

I would like to have this is offline (I won't want to do this via an online service through a browser also just in case the servers are down for what ever the reason may be).

Comment: If you did this, you would then have a Java mobile application in a `.apk` file. Since there's no device that can run such a file, what would the point be? Converting the file won't make it an Android application.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz sir i review my question and post it again soon

Comment: @DavidSchwartz sir as per daverook post suggests that its possible i am confused

Comment: Are you trying to convert the data into a different file format? Or are you trying to convert the application into a different kind of application? Because really what you need is an emulator to run the application on an Android machine.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz convert the file format i use Youwave emulator

Comment: Then that gets back to my question -- why would you want to do that? Youwave can't run Java mobile applications (it has no MIDP support) so what's the point of putting something it can't run into a format it can read?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4477/discussion-between-vignesh-and-david-schwartz)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to Download the .Jar Apps to your PC.

1. Now, Visit [netmite.com](http://www.netmite.com/android/srv/2.0/getapk.php) , You will see lots of Upload Forms.
2. In the Option Two Form, Use the Upload Jar to Browse your .jar File on your PC, Leave every other thing as it is.
3. Then Click on the Get Apk Button below the Forms, You Apps should be Proccessed and Available with the .APK Format.
4. Download and Transfer to your Android Device and Start Using.

Now, I know you have not stated what you're trying to do but you can't just convert a jar or tar file to an apk (an apk is an installation file for Android) hoping it will run or install. First off, it has to be compiled for Android. Android's java library doesn't have all the swing stuff that's in normal java, so the app would have to be completely re-written to work on android and it has not been. (This information from [this website](http://www.justanswer.com/android-devices/6m5ug-convert-jar-file-apk-file-so-program.html))

The only 'offline' version I know of is not free ([upontek.com - j2me to android](http://upontek.com/services/old-projects-j2me-to-android/))

Comment: @thanks for your edit on my question,I prefer freeware offline tool any recommendations?

Comment: It's possible [cuby](http://code.google.com/p/cuby/) is what you want. But it's hard to tell, since you really haven't told us what you want.

Comment: i agree with cuby's feautures which i thought to need it thanks for spending your valuable time for this question